# Is it worth applying for a job to community colleges in the US as a foreigner (no visa)?

Tags: teaching, united-states, university, visa, community-college

Would a small college (e.g., community college) in the US be interested in employing some PhD graduate (as an instructor) that does not already have a visa? Would they bother do the bureaucratic work needed?

Comment: The part about your chances is off-topic, since we don't know you and can't predict future for you. The part about visa may be on topic here, but probably better in expatriates.SE.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if it makes sense applying to community colleges without a visa assuming I can get accepted. It is the visa part I am concerned about, i.e., if such a college would be interested doing the bureaucratic work needed (I am not sure if it is easy or not to hire someone like me that does not already have a visa) to hire me. Do you think I should post my question somewhere else?

Comment: I have posted my question in [exapatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12318/is-it-worth-applying-for-a-job-to-community-colleges-in-the-us-as-a-foreigner-n), but I think my question should stay here as well (at least for now) since it would provide very useful information for recent PhD graduates that want to start their careers.

Comment: Most community colleges don’t have the staff to process an H1B work visa. Given that any job posting attracts dozens if not over a hundred applicants (even at a community college) and given that they only need teachers who are good and not necessarily “the best” — there is no need for them to hire foreign labor.